# Changing timezone for buildPeriodically (cron job) in screwdriver-cd

Tags: screwdriver-cd

I have a job that i need to run everyday at 8 am. But the default timezone for the annotation :

`screwdriver.cd/buildPeriodically: H 8 * * *` is UTC.

Can i change it to some other timezone? (specifically JST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed that upto this date, the only possible settings is UTC.